# Is inner product preserved only by the stabiliser in a finite reflection group?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, coxeter-groups, finite-geometry, reflection-groups

Is the following statement true for finite reflection groups?

Let $G$ be a finite reflection group acting on $\mathbb{R}^n$, let  $x, y\in \mathbb{R}^n$
and let $z$ be in the orbit of $y$. If $\langle x,y\rangle = \langle x, z\rangle$, then there exists $g$ in the stabiliser of $x$ such that $z = gy$.

An important addition: $x$ and $y$ are in the same chamber.

Comment: What is off-topic here? If this is trivial for someone, why not giving a hint where to look for the answer? My co-author and I are genuinely stuck with this, and I thought this is what this web site is for: ask experts in the area for a hint.

Comment: I didn't vote to close the question but when I read it I'm a little confused. Your condition $<x,y>=<x,z>$ seems too easy to satisfy to have any conclusion.  Can't you just choose any $x$ orthogonal to both $y$ and $z$?  Or does $<\cdot, \cdot>$ not represent inner product?

Comment: No, the site is for research level problems, it is definitely not for asking experts to give hints. On the other hand, I am surprised that nobody has given any indication why they have voted to close, and the question does not seem completely trivial to me, so I have voted to reopen.

Comment: No: Take the dihedral group $D_3$ acting on $\mathbb R^2$. You have 6 chambers. Take $y$ in the interior of a chamber, and rotate it to $z$, then $z$ is not in the next chamber, but the second next. Now $x\ne 0$ is perpendicular to $z-y$, so it lies in the interior of a chamber (the one between or its negative), so the stabilizer of $x$ is trivial.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I am sorry I forgot to add that $x$ and $y$ must be in the same chamber. Otherwise this is indeed a bit trivial.

Comment: Now yes: Each chamber is a fundamental domain, and each orbit meets the chamber exactly once. Thus $y=z$ since they are in the same orbit, thus the statement is true.

Comment: What if they are in the closure of the same chamber?

Comment: The same. For reflection groups the closed chamber is a fundamental domain = the orbit space.

Answer (score 2):

Compilation of my remarks:

The answer to the original question is no:
Take the dihedral group $D_3$ acting on $\mathbb ℝ^2$. You have 6 chambers. Take $y$ in the interior of a chamber, and rotate it to $z$, then $z$ is not in the next chamber, but the second next. Now $x\ne 0$ is perpendicular to $z−y$, so it lies in the interior of a chamber (the one between or its negative), so the stabilizer of $x$ is trivial.

If $y$ and $z$ lie in the same chamber: The closed chamber is a fundamental domain and is the orbit space (no further identification on walls). Thus $y=z$ since they are in the same orbit, thus the statement is true.